# Xamarin Forms - Image to String and reverse

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, byte

I saw so much of post on google and I couldn't make it works.
However, it seems so easy and logic to get an `Xamarin.Forms.Image` into a `String` but I'm not able to realize it. I tried from stream, from platform renderer, still doesn't work.

I want it to work on every platform, can you help me?

Thank !

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Because my boss wants to stock it on a mysql case... so I need this image in string in order to save it. I know how to generate the image from the string.. But image to string I can't find it

Comment: @Emixam23 you want a string representation of a image?

Comment: Yeah.. then I can store it and convert it back to an image

Comment: you need to use the original source image that was used to create the Xamarin.Forms.Image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin - Show image from base64 string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080258/xamarin-show-image-from-base64-string)

Comment: Yeah Gerald it's a duplication of a similar problem, but this post doesn't answer my question which is to convert my Image into a string. Maybe I don't understand something, so if I do, can you please answer?

Comment: the Image control doesn't allow you to access the underlying image data.  That's why you need to use the original source (file, url, stream, etc) that you used to create the Image.

Comment: Oh ok you're right, i found the solution with your message. I'll put an answer later :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a string representation of a Image then first you need to get the `bytes` from this image and then convert it into a string format like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

But first we need to get the byte from the image, Xamarin.Forms's Image is a `View` which contains a `Source`

```
public class Image : View, IImageController, IElementConfiguration<Image>
{
    public ImageSource Source { get; set; }
}
```

That source is used to load the image that will be shown, we have a some kinds of `ImageSource` (`FileImageSource`,  `StreamImageSource`, `UriImageSource`) but if I'm not mistaken currently no way to transform ImageSource to `bytes` in Xamarin.Forms, but we can use native code for such

**Android**

In Android we can use `IImageSourceHandler` to transform an ImageSource to `Bitmap` and form the `Bitmap` to bytes

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ImageLoader))]
public class ImageLoader : IImageLoader
{
    public async Task<byte[]> LoadImageAsync(ImageSource source)
    {
        IImageSourceHandler handler = GetHandlerFor(source);
        var bmp = await handler.LoadImageAsync(source, Forms.Context);
        byte[] result;
        using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await bmp.CompressAsync(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 95, ms);
            result = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            await ms.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private IImageSourceHandler GetHandlerFor(ImageSource source)
    {
        IImageSourceHandler result;
        if (source is FileImageSource) result = new FileImageSourceHandler();
        else if (source is StreamImageSource) result = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
        else result = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**iOS**

Same as Android we can use IImageSourceHandler to transform into UIImage and then get the bytes from it

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ImageLoader))]
public class ImageLoader : IImageLoader
{
    public async Task<byte[]> LoadImageAsync(ImageSource source)
    {
        IImageSourceHandler handler = GetHandlerFor(source);
        UIImage image = await handler.LoadImageAsync(source);
        using (NSData imageData = image.AsPNG())
        {
            return imageData.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private IImageSourceHandler GetHandlerFor(ImageSource source)
    {
        IImageSourceHandler result;
        if (source is FileImageSource) result = new FileImageSourceHandler();
        else if (source is StreamImageSource) result = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
        else result = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
        return result;
    }
}
```

#Forms
Note that I inserted `[assembly: Dependecy(typeof(ImageLoader))]` so we can use the Xamarin Forms to recognize and bring the correct ImageLoader from each Platform so we use it like this

```
byte[] bytes = await DependencyService.Get<IImageLoader>().LoadImageAsync(imgSource);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) //convert the binary to a string representation in base64
```

#note
`IImageLoader`is a simple interface like the following

```
public interface IImageLoader
{
    Task<byte[]> LoadImageAsync(ImageSource source);
}
```

Comment: The android snippet is getting stuck on `var bmp = await handler.LoadImageAsync(source, Forms.Context);`, any idea why?

Comment: Heinst, Check: Task<Bitmap> LoadImageAsync (ImageSource imagesource, Context context, CancellationToken cancelationToken = default(CancellationToken)), you should look for Application Output and make sure no CancelException